# Prevent window from spanning multiple monitors

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Is there any simple way to prevent WPF windows from spanning multiple monitors in a dual-monitor setup? With "simple" I mean without writing code-behind that measures the monitor size and assigns a width to the Window.

I would prefer if a window uses only the part available on the current monitor (where "current" means the monitor with the currently focused window). It is OK if the user resizes the window such that it covers both monitors, but at the time when the window opens it shall stay on a single monitor.

Here is an example:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MultiMonitorTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Open Window" 
                Height="70" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="165,147,0,0" 
                Name="button1" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="179" 
                Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWIndow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MultiMonitorTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window2 win = new Window2();
            win.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Window2.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MultiMonitorTest.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window2" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt" 
                 Margin="10" 
                 Background="LightPink" 
                 AcceptsTab="True" 
                 AcceptsReturn="True" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window2.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MultiMonitorTest
{
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            txt.Text = new string('x', 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

When clicking the "Open window" button, the new window opens across two monitors. I would prefer if Window2 stayed completely within the current monitor.

Comment: What sort of desktop setup are you referring to? If it's a single desktop across multiple monitors handled by the graphics card (not windows) then this will be very hard to achieve as windows only sees one monitor. If, on the other hand, it's being handled by windows, I haven't experienced the problem you're describing but will have a test later if nobody has answered

Comment: @Basic: the Windows 7 "Display" panel shows two monitors; i.e. Windows knows that there are two monitors. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Use the Winforms' Screen class to discover monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the same width, height (and perhaps position) as the parent window on the second one. Without additional code, I don't think you can really force the window to span across two monitors. You can however, with limited code start it on one instead of two.

```
WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen; // in your Window Xaml

//and combine with

Rectangle workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea; // Reference System.Windows.Forms and set left, top, width and height accordingly.
```

This is the best you can do I think without having to write 'large amounts' of code (this will center it to the working area of the primary screen). If you really want to limit your window to span across multiple monitors is of course possible, but requires some work.
A good starting point would be the [WindowInteropHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) class.